# How to get the an image from mysql database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code which should search for pictured in mysql database, am not sure if it is working,

I want to get the images the user search for and post them in the html, can i do this?

**Here is my code**

```
<?php 
    require('connect.php');
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
      if(isset($_GET['go'])){ 
      if(preg_match("/^[  a-zA-Z]+/", $_POST['name'])){ 
      $name=$_POST['name']; 
      //connect  to the database 
      //-query  the database table 
      $sql="SELECT * FROM cards WHERE name LIKE '%$searchQuery'"; 
      //-run  the query against the mysql query function 
      $result=mysql_query($sql); 
      //-create  while loop and loop through result set 
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
              $name = $row['name'];
                $id = $row['id'];
      } 
      } 
      else{ 
      echo  "<p>Please enter a search query</p>"; 
      } 
      } 
      } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you store image's path in database ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen yea, images stored like this, filename/pictureName.jpg

Comment: May i know the coloumn  Name that you use

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen column name is 'name'

Comment: I have posted the answer, I thought you would use `image` as the name :) I will update my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the image [Where you have stored the image's path in db]

You shall just echo the coloumn with the image tag

```
echo "<img src =".$row['name'].">";
```

Note :

You should point the image the path where the image is stored in the files

Some thing like

```
echo "<img src ='assets/images/".$row['name']."'>"
```